# Cant access image in flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

Hi i am trying to access images of map from a folder located in static folder.Here is the folder structure,

```
       |-->flask.py
       |-->static----->map-->images
       |
       |-->templates
```

In the java script file setting the `IMAGE_URL` as `IMAGE_URL ="/static/map.png"` works but i want to create a folder inside static as map and access image like `IMAGE_URL ="/static/map/map.png`.When i change the static folder path in server like `app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path = "/static/map", static_folder = "map")` all bootstrap things get messed up.Is there anyway to access image from map folder inside static directory?

NOTE:I am doing this in a java script file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your static folder. Just include the relative path from it:

```
IMAGE_URL = url_for('static', filename='map/map.png')
```

Comment: This doesn't work.I am getting an url_for not defined error.

Comment: `from flask import url_for`

Comment: Actually i am doing this in a java script file.

Comment: Ah. I see. Your url would be `/static/map/map.png` without changing your static folder. If you want to use `url_for` in JS, you can install `Flask-JSGlue`.